# HWUT: parameters on command line

Tags: c, unit-testing, hwut

On the command line prompt, is it possible to pass a parameter to the hwut command, e.g. in order to use that parameter as an identifier to open a particular serial port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the easiest way is to use environment variables. Let's say your test is written in "C", then do

```
   set MY_VARIABLE=4711    # DOS
   export MY_VARIABLE=4711 # Unix & Co
   hwut my-test.exe
```

where the file "my-test.c" is the source of "my-test.exe" and contains

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ...
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       ...
       const char* MyVariable_str = getenv("MY_VARIABLE");
       int         my_variable;

       my_variable = MyVariable_str ? atoi(MyVariable_str) : -1;
       ...
   }
```

The propper solution, of course, is to have some configuration file which is 
configured globally and parsed by the test applications. The overhead for that, however, might not always be justified.